# How to create multiple rows which contains two text boxes and labels above them in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create three rows. In each row I want to have two textboxes with labels above them. Right now, I have this html code:

```css
.firstRow, .secondRow, .thirdRow {
      display: inline-block;
}

label, .textBox {
      display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstRow">
      <label for="name1">Name1</label>
      <input class="textBox" formControlName="name1" />
      <label for="name2">Name2</label>
      <input class="textBox" formControlName="name2" />
</div>
<div class="secondRow">
      <label for="name3">Name3</label>
      <input class="textBox" formControlName="name3" />
      <label for="name4">Name4</label>
      <input class="textBox" formControlName="name4" />
</div>
<div class="thirdRow">
      <label for="name5">Name5</label>
      <input class="textBox" formControlName="name5" />
      <label for="name6">Name6</label>
      <input class="textBox" formControlName="name6" />
</div>
```

The outcome is in this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lcav5xje/

What should I change?

Comment: Did you try using a `table` ?

Comment: @Fifi a `table` should not be used in this case. Tables are for data, not layout. It's bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the snippet using simple  `display:flex;`

also no need to add separate class for every row

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.form-grp {
  margin: 10px
}
.form-grp label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-grp">
    <label for="name1">Name1</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name1" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-grp">
    <label for="name2">Name2</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name2" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-grp">
    <label for="name3">Name3</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name3" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-grp">
    <label for="name4">Name4</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name4" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-grp">
    <label for="name5">Name5</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name5" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-grp">
    <label for="name6">Name6</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name6" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grid` to align the items.

example:

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; /*Two columns*/
  grid-auto-flow: column /*to align the input under the label*/;
  justify-content: start; /*sticked to the left*/
  grid-gap: 0 10px; /*horizontal space between  inputs*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="grid">
    <label for="name1">Name1</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name1" />
    <label for="name2">Name2</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name2" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="grid">

    <label for="name3">Name3</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name3" />
    <label for="name4">Name4</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name4" />
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="grid">

    <label for="name5">Name5</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name5" />
    <label for="name6">Name6</label>
    <input class="textBox" formControlName="name6" />
      </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: To have labels above the input you also need to set "label" back  to display:block

Comment: @KareemDabbeet, Thank you for your time and effort, your answer is also good. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

**Demo**

```css
.firstRow,
.secondRow,
.thirdRow {
  display: inherit;
}

.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstRow">
  <div class="inner">
    <label for="name1">Name1</label>
    <input class="textBox" formcontrolname="name1">
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <label for="name2">Name2</label>
    <input class="textBox" formcontrolname="name2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try always to wrap your code within snippet, It'll be better to view and see the result